# BuddyPress - A hook available to hide custom born date on public profile view?

Tags: filters, hooks, buddypress

I'm trying to hide some fields on public BuddyPress profiles, it is possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know, but you can hide via css or javascript the areas; via css:

```
#id_or_.class_of_elemet { display:none; }
```

Comment: Easy, but maybe a hook in some loop? Thanks.